# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero (python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am using the below code to bypass divide by zero error still getting one, not able to figure out what's actually going wrong here.

```
df.loc[:,'B to A Ratio'] =np.where(df.loc[:,'A']!=0,df.loc[:,'B']/df.loc[:,'A'],np.nan)
```

FYI, I am doing this operation on a data frame created from pivot table. Column 'A' & 'B' here are just for Illustration.

Comment: Because you are still performing division by zero at : `df.loc[:,'B']/df.loc[:,'A']`. `np.where` does the choosing thereafter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As commented by @Divakar, when you use `np.where`, the division is still fully evaluated for all the values in the two series; To avoid dividing by zero, you can convert zeros to `nan` before division since any value divided by `nan` gives `nan`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": [1,2,0,3,4],
        "B": [0,2,1,0,1]
    })
​
df.B.div(df.A.where(df.A != 0, np.nan))

#0    0.00
#1    1.00
#2     NaN
#3    0.00
#4    0.25
#dtype: float64
```

---

Also not sure what your pandas version is, dividing by zero in pandas 0.19 ~ 0.20 gives `inf` instead of raising an error

```
df.B / df.A

#0    0.000000
#1    1.000000
#2         inf
#3    0.000000
#4    0.250000
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks this works!, alternatively I used the below code:    
                                                                                                              data['B to A Ratio'] = data.apply(lambda x :x['B']/x['A'] if x['A']!=0 else np.nan,axis=1)

Comment: I am using pandas version 0.20.1, its not giving inf

Comment: I don't have `0.20.1`. But `0.19.2` and `0.20.3` does give `inf`. Maybe you are dividing numpy arrays instead of pandas Series, in which case I get warning messages.