# Open a new CSV file after certain number of iterations

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This code calculates the ratio of two columns of price data from a csv file and writes the ratio to another. AFter a few hundred calculations though this code gets slow. How can I open a new CSV file to store the ratios in after a given number of them have already been calculated.

```
sector_name = ['asset_management', 'basic_materials', 'conglomerates', 'consumer_goods', 'financials', 'healthcare', 'industrial_goods', 'services', 'technology', 'utilities']

def data_sector_ratios():

    for sector,name in zip(list_all_sectors, sector_name):

        for ticker in sector:

            df = pd.read_csv(.../price_data_file.csv)
            df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False )],axis = 1, inplace = True)
            fieldnames = ["PAIR", "RATIO"]

            with open(.../sector_ratios.csv, 'w') as file:                
                writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
                writer.writeheader()
                cols = list(df.columns[1:])
                for i,c in enumerate(cols[:-1]):
                    for c2 in cols[i+1:]:
                        df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)] = df[c]/df[c2]
                        dff = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)]
                        dff.dropna(inplace=True)
                        length = len(dff.index)                        
                        start = dff.iloc[0]
                        end = dff.iloc[length-1]
                        change = str((end - start)/start)
                        pair = df.columns[-1]                        
                        row = {"PAIR": pair, "RETURNS": change}
                        writer.writerow(row)
                        print("{}/{} RATIO CALCULATED".format(c,c2))
```

Some sectors have ~700 columns. Therefore (700^2 - 700)/2 = ~490'000 ratios. After about 20'000 create a new file ex: basic_materials_ratios_2 or something. The price data csv files looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsDXT.png

EDIT:

Output CSV file. I just want to keep adding rows every time a ratio is calculated by the for loop.

```
PAIR        RATIO
A/AA       xxxxxx
A/AABA     xxxxxx
A/AAL      xxxxxx
.....      ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would suggest sticking within pandas until your data is ready to be exported.**

There are ways to optimize your code within pandas to make it super fast.

**First, here's a slightly neater version of the operation you want to perform.**

```
cols = df.columns[1:] # assuming your first column is your index, move it there

# no need to enumerate here
for col_1 in cols:
    for col_2 in cols:
        # skip unnecessary computations
        if col_1 == col_2:
            continue
        df[f'{col_1}/{col_2}'] = (df[col_1]/df[col_2]).replace(abs(np.inf), np.nan)
```

**Assuming your data is loaded in 1 giant df, you want to identify where the gaps in the execution are taking place.**

- My assumption is that your data has a lot of `null` values or zeros, in which case massive frame divisions will become super slow. You can avoid this by wrapping your division in a lambda or list operator: `df.B.div(df.A.where(df.A != 0, np.nan))` *[taken from this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347721/10521959)*.
- Perhaps your dataframe is so massive that is overwhelms your machine's memory. Here I would suggest you operate chunk-wise.
- Perhaps your data has mixed types and is getting slowed down by converting for each computation. Go scrub.

All in all, your requested/proposed solution to this slow computation is fantastically innovative but frankly will be a large waste of time. Optimize within pandas period.

Comment: Hey thank you for taking the time! I tried your code and it works perfectly but when I add in a df.to_csv at the end it slows it down quite a bit. Something I am missing?

Comment: If your df is large, it will take a little but of time to write the csv. If you're using your data for external use, not much to do there. If internal use, consider exporting to a pickle.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using panda's read_csv() function but not the corresponding df.write_csv()?

It will be much simpler and probably much faster if you load in the dataframe, transform the data as you need and do a write_csv() at the end.

If you want to create multiple files, you would just need to slice the dataframe for the rows you want.

Comment: When I write to_csv I'm not sure how to write new rows with different values. I know how to add columns but how do you place different values in each row?

Comment: In addition to the answer below I would highly recommend checking out the pandas docs a bit more. it depends on what you're trying to do.
if you're just adding data:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html
if you need to change data in an existing dataframe you could do something like df.apply()
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thanks I will review the docs. I made an edit. I just want to add a row with a ratio every time the for loop calculates one.